# Can I make assumptions in BFS and DFS?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

I'm reviewing the concepts of Depth-first search (DFS) and Breath-first search (BFS), but I always forget if I can assume some rules.

I know that in a DFS I will start with the root and go as far as I can, before come back, (...)
and in a BFS I will start visiting the root and all its neighbors, (...)

My question is, in case that I have more than one option, can I make assumptions or "rules"?

i.e.:

- DSF in a graph that my nodes are letters - I decided that from the root I will start search in the alphabetical order.
- BFS in a tree - I decided that I will always start from the neighbor from the left.

Is okay define this things or there is a major rule (besides the purpose of the search)?

Answer (score 3):

No there is no major rule for doing that. Based on your purpose for using BFS or DFS, if it is important what order you use you should do that, otherwise any order -Alphabetically, randomly, etc- is fine. Only important thing is that in BFS you should first meet the immediate neighbors of root, the do the same for all seen nodes, in the order you have seen. for example if **R** is the root of a tree and **[LC, RC]** are its children. and each one respectively has children **[LC1, LC2]** and **[RC1, RC2]** while doing the BFS, after visiting R you can visit LC and RC in any order you like. However, if you first meet LC the you have to first check LC1 and LC2 then RC1 and RC2. Again you can check LC1 and LC2 in any order. And making this happen is really easy using a ***Queue***. Hence, the first thing you visit, in the next level you will see its neighbors first.